# Promise.allSettled with timing for each call

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

Is there a technique or javascript library to effectively perform the equivalent of `Promises.allSettled([Array of tasks]);` and access the number of milliseconds each task took?

For example, if I make 5 concurrent API calls to remote services, I'd like to see if it would be worth grouping them into two separate calls to process the fast ones while the slow ones are still loading.  If they all take around the same amount of time to load, it wouldn't be worth the effort.

Comment: If you can process results as they come in without waiting for all to complete, why don't you just do so?  You can process results as they arrive and still have a `Promise.allSettled()` that tells you when they are all complete.  You can do both without any compromise.

Comment: I'm building a web page with results that are interleaved from different sources and is fluid in design, often accessed by phone or tablet.  It takes me awhile to keep it from looking unstable when I render it piecemeal.

Comment: Yeah, rendering piecemeal can be visually disturbing.  Always a tradeoff between incremental rendering that starts rendering sooner, but then might jump around a bit while filling the content vs. waiting until you have all the content and rendering all at once.  I'm not a fan of making the user wait to see anything, but if the page jumps around a bit as various parts get rendered, that's no good either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just intercept the completion of all the promises and record the time for each while still passing them to `Promise.allSettled()`

```
function allSettledTimed(promises) {
    const start = Date.now();
    return Promise.allSettled(promises.map((p, index) => {
        return p.finally(() => {
            console.log(`[${index}] took ${Date.now() - start}ms to complete`);
        });
    }));
}
```

Or, if you want the timing results to be embedded into the `Promise.allSettled()` results, you can do that like this:

```
function allSettledTimed(promises) {
    const start = Date.now();
    const times = new Array(promises.length);
    return Promise.allSettled(promises.map((p, index) => {
        return p.finally(() => {
            times[index] = Date.now() - start;
        });
    })).then(results => {
        // transfer times over to the result array
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            results[i].time = times[i];
        }
        return results;
    });
}
```

Note: This implementation assumes you passed an array (so it can use `.map()`), not an arbitrary iterable.  With a little more code, it could accept an arbitrary iterable if that was necessary.

Comment: This fit nicely without having to rework my handling of the results.  Just the section using `p.finally` was sufficient for my needs, giving me an array of comparable `times`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple wrapper to time each task, and return both the result of each task and its duration.

This code creates 3 tasks, each of which delay for a random duration between 0 and 5 seconds. We wrap each task using the timeTask function. The duration is measured in milliseconds.

```js
(async () => {
  console.log('This will take up to 5 seconds to complete')

  const tasks = Array.from({length: 3}, (_,i) =>
    new Promise(resolve => 
      setTimeout(() => resolve(`task ${i} result`), Math.random()*5000|0))
  )
  
  const timeTask = async (task, startMs = Date.now()) => 
    ({value: await task, duration: Date.now() - startMs})

  let results = await Promise.allSettled(tasks.map(t => timeTask(t)))

  console.log(results)
})();
```